# How should I go about reflections in opengl?

Tags: opengl, reflection

As far as I know there are 2 ways,

1. "Flip" the scene on the y axis and add some blending - Avoiding this since I've added deferred rendering, which doesn't support transparency without mixing with forward rendering.
2. Render the scene to a cube map and use the "reflect" function in GLSL - seems to be good for certain objects, but it's a plane I'm trying to do reflections with.

Any suggestions? I've considered rendering the scene to an orthographic texture.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the application? Are you looking for mirror-like high-res reflections or [more basic ones](http://www.legenddiaries.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Graphics.jpg)?